# autostart webserver and programm

Tags: c++, node.js, shell, yocto, autostart

I'm working on a Yocto based system. My problem is that I can't start my programm written in C++ and the webserver (node.js) at the same time right after the boot of my device.

I already tried this in /etc/init.d:

```
#! /bin/bash
/home/ProjectFolder/myProject
cd /home/myapp && DEBUG=myapp:* npm start

exit 0
```

I changed the rights after creating the script by

```
chmod +x ./startProg.sh
```

After that I linked it by

```
update-rc.d startProg.sh defaults
```

After reboot the system only starts the C++-programm. I tried some other possibilities like seperating the two comands in different shell-scripts, but that didn't work out any better.

Is there any option I missed or did I make any mistake trying to put those two processes into the autostart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This of course isn't a C++ or Node.js question. A shell script is a list of commands that are executed **in order**, unless specified otherwise. So your shell script runs your two programs in the order specified, first `myProject` and when that's done `npm` will be started.

This is the same as what would happen from the prompt and the solution is the same: `/home/ProjectFolder/myProject &`

Comment: Thank you. The "&" solved my problem. Sorry, that I put this into the wrong categories.